# Convert format json into csv

Tags: python, pandas

I have json

```
{
  "licenses": [
    {
      "name": "",
      "id": 0,
    }
  ],
  "info": {
    "contributor": "",
    "version": "",
    "year": ""
  }
```

I have a script which read json and save new csv with `licenses`parameter.
How can I add extra parameter such as `info`? with help of pandas

```
import json
import pandas as pd


data = json.load(open('file.json'))
df = pd.DataFrame(data["licenses"])

df.to_csv('test.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: What should the result look like?

Comment: new csv file with licenses and info attributes. for now I can add just 1 of them

Comment: `pd.json_normalize(data,record_path='licenses')` ?

Comment: @Manakin I can do same with `df = pd.DataFrame(data["licenses"])` Just need extra parameter to add more key

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have `extra_info` that maps licenses ids to some extra information. Below is code that merges base data with licenses and extra info resulting in final licenses data having extra `info` field. These two lists are joined based on comon `id` field. In my code I skip reading from JSON file, I think it is obvious and trivial.

You have to have some correspondense between `data` and `extra_info`. I supposed that both of these datas have unique common `id` field. Because if there is nothing in common how would you tell what info corresponds to what license in data? At least they have to be corresponded between each other by having same position in the list.

[Try it online!](https://repl.it/@moytrage/StackOverflow65957341#main.py)

```
data = {
  "licenses": [
    {
      "name": "name0",
      "id": 0,
    },
    {
      "name": "name1",
      "id": 1,
    },
  ],
  "info": {
    "contributor": "",
    "version": "",
    "year": ""
  }
}
# Extra info fields indexed by id.
extra_info = [
    {
        'id': 0,
        'info': 'info0',
    },
    {
        'id': 1,
        'info': 'info1',
    },
]
import json, pandas as pd
info_map = {e['id'] : e for e in extra_info}
licenses = [{**e, 'info': info_map[e['id']]['info']} for e in data['licenses']]
df = pd.DataFrame(licenses)
df.to_csv('0491.csv', index = False)
```

Output:

```
name,id,info
name0,0,info0
name1,1,info1
```